# Double Pointer two strcture array compilation error

Tags: c, syntax

I have this Structure defined:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t short_addr;
    uint64_t ieee_addr;
    uint8_t  LQI;
    uint16_t PANId;
} CAMERA;
```

And I declared an array of it, like this:

```
static CAMERA device_list [ MAX_NUMBER_OF_DEVICES ];
```

all this is defined and declared in a specific module.
Now, I want to create a pointer to that array from the main module from within a new structure.
but I get compilation errors, and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

```
typedef struct
{
 CAMERA * device_list[ MAX_NUMBER_OF_DEVICES ];
} main_struct;
main_struct MAIN_STRUCT;
```

But the problem is that I can't assign the value of the pointer to that.

```
MAIN_STRUCT.device_list = device_list;
```

Caused the following compilation error:

```
Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

What's the right way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign to an array. You also declare it wrong in `main_struct`, it's enough to declare it as a pointer (right now you have it declared as as array of pointers.)

```
typedef struct
{
 CAMERA * device_list;
} main_struct;
```

And it should work.

If you really want it as an array, then declare it as an array:

```
typedef struct
{
 CAMERA device_list[ MAX_NUMBER_OF_DEVICES ];
} main_struct;
```

And copy from the other array to the new array:

```
memcpy(MAIN_STRUCT.device_list, device_list, sizeof(CAMERA) * MAX_NUMBER_OF_DEVICES);
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that I can't view this structure correctly in debugger, it only shows the first CAMERA strcture, as you  define it as a pointer to CAMERA, not a CAMERA array.

Comment: @Mellowcandle Added example of how you could do if you really want arrays.

Comment: This won't work, because now I have two different copies of the structure. I want it to be a pointer to that structure.

Comment: @Mellowcandle Ok, in that case you will have to live with the debugger only showing the first value. However, in the debugger you can still reach the data as it was an array, either by `device_list[x]` or `*(device_list + x)`.

Comment: @Joachim: I strongly disagree with your implementation! You are copying unknown data into the content of the device_ist array... any access to an index other than 0 will definitely yield undefined results. If you have to do this, memset to zero and copy one element to the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
typedef struct
{
 CAMERA * device_list
} main_struct;
main_struct MAIN_STRUCT;



{

   MAIN_STRUCT myMainStruct;
   myMainStruct.device_list = device_list;

}
```

With what you are doing you create an array of pointers to main struct;
hth

Mario

Comment: The problem with this method is that I can't view this structure correctly in debugger, it only shows the first CAMERA strcture, as you define it as a pointer to CAMERA, not a CAMERA array.

Comment: use print *myMainStruct.device_list ;-)